# Creating custom home directory

Tags: directory, home-directory

I need to make custom directory DIR which has everything from /etc/skel directory, plus Documents and Downloads directories. This file has to be used to create home directories for users, and I found the mkhomedir_helper command the best way to do it, but I don't know how to change default directory it copies files from /etc/skel to DIR. Can someone help?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Please add the new information to your question.

Comment: So I need to make home directory for new user that was created with adduer but with option -no-create-home. That home directory must not contain files from /etc/skel, but from custom directory that I created and named skeleton. Is there a way to do this using mkhomedir_helper or usermod, or anything else?